# Raster Subtraction with 2 different sized rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, spatial-outliers

I am a beginner to ArcGIS and am using it for my dissertation. I have two raster files of different areas and subtracted one from the other to find the difference between the two, however, it has given me a result which falls outside the boundaries of the smaller raster, why?[image: you can see that the smaller raster ends just above where the difference is shown]

Comment: Can you explain what this image is showing?  How can we differentiate between your two rasters?

Comment: I'm guessing you subtracted the smaller raster from the larger raster.  This means that outside the boundaries of the smaller raster, where only the larger raster exists, you will just get the data from the larger raster.  But some more clarification as to what we're seeing in that image and the actual process you followed to extract them would allow us to help you.